# Download entire group chat history from openfire

Tags: xmpp, openfire, jsjac, groupchat

I am using `openfire` as chat server and `JsJac` as client library for chat web application. JsJac working fine with one to one chat and groupchat. I have added monitoring plugin in openfire for message archiving. Now I want functionality of downloading entire group chat history.

Question : Is it possible to download entire group chat using JsJac or there is any other better approach available for that?

Thanks

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: I want to know how to get chat history in JsJac.

Comment: You need to build [XMPP packet](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#business_rules) using [JsJac IQ](http://sstrigler.github.io/JSJaC/JSJaCIQ.html) for downloading group chat

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply, I will try the same...